# Controlling vertical padding in tabularx for itemize

Tags: tabularx, itemize

I am having a small challenge in controlling the vertical spacing in tabularx. As you can see below, the top and bottom padding appear to be more only when using itemize (perhaps with other `\begin{} \end{}` also). I have removed all vertical separators in the itemize by using `nosep` as can be seen in the sample outside of tabularx below. So my guess is this is something happening within tabularx.

I tried using `makecell`, and also `\extrarowheight` (as suggested by some other threads), but the vertical spaces remain unchanged.

Would appreciate any help!

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
  %{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}             % doesn't work
  %\setcellgapes{0pt}                            % doesn't work either
  %\makegapedcells                               % ditto
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    Col 1 & Col 2\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{Note the vertical space above and below this cell.}\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\linewidth=\hsize}X|}{
    \begin{itemize}[nosep,align=left,leftmargin=*]
      \item The first item in itemize, note the vertical space above this. A bit more to show.
      \item The second item in itemize, note the vertical space below this.
    \end{itemize}}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \hrule
  \begin{itemize}[nosep,align=left,leftmargin=*]
    \item The first item in itemize, note the vertical space above this. A bit more to show.
    \item The second item in itemize, note the vertical space below this.
  \end{itemize}
  \hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, it would be better to add vertical padding to all cells. LateX tables often look quite tight. This can be done with the `cellspace`  package.

Comment: Yes, the cells are too tight by default. When I used the `makecell` package and `\setcellgapes{<some-value>pt}`, all cells got that padding, however the one in question above had more padding than the rest.

Comment: You can define a `\compress` command as meaning `\@minipagetrue` and use `>{\compress\arraybackslash}X` for the column containing the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `enumitem` package provides the options `before=...` and `after=...` to control what comes before and after the list itself. One can use these options to encase the list in a `minipage`; this is useful because, by default, any whitespace padding above and below a `minipage` is eliminated automatically.

As the example below shows, it's actually preferable to use the `minipage` with the `[t]` ("top") positinioning specifier, as that will assure that the first line in the first list item will be aligned with lines elsewhere in the table (here: Col0).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent % <-- important
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|}
    \hline
    Col 0 & Col 1 & Col 2\\
    \hline
    abcxyz & 
    \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{%
    Note the vertical space above and below this cell.}\\
    \hline
    abcxyz & 
    \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\linewidth=\hsize}X|}{%
    \begin{itemize}[nosep,align=left,leftmargin=*,
                    before={\begin{minipage}{\hsize}}, % <-- new
                    after={\end{minipage}}             % <-- new
                   ]
      \item The first item in itemize, note the vertical space above this. 
            A bit more to show.
      \item The second item in itemize, note the vertical space below this.
    \end{itemize}}\\
    \hline
    abcxyz & 
    \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\linewidth=\hsize}X|}{%
    \begin{itemize}[nosep,align=left,leftmargin=*,
                    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}}, % <-- with "[t]"
                    after={\end{minipage}}%               % <-- new
                   ]%
      \item The first item in itemize, note the vertical space above this. 
            A bit more to show.
      \item The second item in itemize, note the vertical space below this.
    \end{itemize}}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \hrule
  \begin{itemize}[nosep,align=left,leftmargin=*]
    \item The first item in itemize, note the vertical space above this. A bit more to show.
    \item The second item in itemize, note the vertical space below this.
  \end{itemize}
  \hrule
  \begin{itemize}[nosep,align=left,leftmargin=*] % note use of "\strut" directives
    \item \strut The first item in itemize, note the vertical space above this. A bit more to show.
    \item The second item in itemize, note the vertical space below this.\strut
  \end{itemize}
  \hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mico, it worked. However (and it has got nothing to do with your solution), when using minipage, I realized that I could have the table span across pages. I am also using `parcol` - dual columns throughout the document, and the table above I am discussing is in the right column (I am actually playing with a resume template that I am fully customizing, and in turn learning TeX). So now I need `longtable`, `tabularx` and `parcol`, and `longtable` is not playing well with `parcol` at all. I may need to give up some of my requirements in order not to make it too complex.